# Using podman instead of docker for the Docker@2 task in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, podman

Our build agent is running Podman 3.4.2 and there is a global alias in place for each terminal session that simply replaces docker with podman, so the command `docker --version` yields `podman version 3.4.2` as a result.

The goal is to use podman for the `Docker@2` task in a Azure DevOps pipeline:

```yaml
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    repository: aspnet-web-mhi
    dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tags: |
      $(tag)
```

Turns out I was a bit naive in my assumptions, that this would work as the ado_agent is having none of it:

> ##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

Is there a way to make that replacement work without too much fuss? I'd avoid scripting everything by myself to use podman instead of docker and push it to a registry, if I can avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried symlinking docker to podman? or craeting an executable bash script that passes all arguments from it to podman?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I needed to make progress on this, I've decided to go the down the bash-route and built, pushed, pulled and run the images manually. This is the gist of it:

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Build Docker Image for DemoWeb
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        podman build -f $(dockerfilePath) -t demoweb:$(tag) .
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Login and Push to ACR
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        podman login -u $(acrServicePrincipal) -p $(acrPassword) $(acrName)
        podman push demoweb-mhi:$(tag) $(acrName)/demoweb:$(tag)
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Pull image from ACR
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        podman pull $(acrName)/demoweb:$(tag) --creds=$(acrServicePrincipal):$(acrPassword)
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Run container
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        podman run -p 8080:80 --restart unless-stopped $(acrName)/demoweb:$(tag)
```

If you decide to go down that route, please make sure to *not* expose your service principal and password as variables in your yml file, but create them as secrets.

I'll keep this question open - maybe someone with more expertise in handling GNU/Linux finds a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You could install package `podman-docker` as well. It installs a wrapper in /usr/bin/docker that points to /usr/bin/podman. So tasks that originally use docker binary (or even docker socket) can be run transparently as podman like Docker@2 build and push.

```bash
cat /usr/bin/docker

#!/bin/sh
[ -e /etc/containers/nodocker ] || \
echo "Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg." >&2
exec /usr/bin/podman "$@"
```